# Laravel Eloquent - Sort client records by region using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have my model, controller and database migration already working and I'm able to retrieve display the data.

clients.blade.php

```
@foreach ($table_companies as $client)
    {{ $client['geography'] }} - {{ $client['company'] }} - {{ $client['country'] }} - {{$client['industry'] }}
@endforeach
```

ClientsController.php

```
public function showClients() {

    $table_companies = Clients::selectRaw(' name_company company, geography geography, country country, type_industry industry, emphasize bold')   
      ->groupBy('company', 'geography', 'country', 'industry', 'bold')
      ->get()
      ->toArray();

    return view('about.our-clients', compact('our-clients', 'table_companies'));
```

2017_12_12_173246_create_clients_table.php

```
Schema::create('table_companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // $table->increments('id');
    // $table->timestamps();
    $table->increments('ID_CLIENT');
    $table->string('NAME_COMPANY');
    $table->string('TYPE_INDUSTRY');
    $table->string('COUNTRY');
    $table->string('GEOGRAPHY');
    $table->integer('emphasize');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

}

What I'm trying to do is to format the data and group it by geography passing url parameter

Example 1: `/our-clients.php?geography=North_America`

And group them like:

NORTH AMERICA
USA

### Aetna | Bayview

CANADA
Frontier | Federal Court

Example 2: `/our-clients.php?geography=Europe`
EUROPE
BELGIUM

### Digip | Sonoc

DENMARK
Skandina | National Police

Any ideas?

Comment: Look into https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-maptogroups if that helps you... this can group them together after you retrieved them from the db. Just play around a bit with that function, I think it's exactly what you want. PS: or wait, maybe you want filter? I think you want filter and then a mapToGroups()? I will write some answer, just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads as if you want to filter for geography? Or group by? But if it's the latter, why do you have that get parameter? Not entirely clear.

So if you wanna filter, you should obviously include a where('geography' , request()->geography) in your query.

You could also get all and filter afterwards with the filter() method
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter

```
$filtered_table_companies = $table_companies->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->geography == request()->geography;
});
```

I would suggest the Eloquent version, if you don't need the other regions anywhere else.

If you want to group by country, I would then suggest
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-maptogroups

```
$grouped_table_companies = $table_companies->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$item->geography] => $item;
});
```

Try this in tinker once to see the output of it and try to understand it.
You can then go through that collection with 2 nested foreach in your blade file like

```
@foreach($grouped_table_companies as $region => $regional_table_companies)
    <div>{{ $region }}</div>
    @foreach($regional_table_companies as $table_company)
        // output stuff here
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you wanted a groupby early on instead of a filter, you can obviously perform 2 mapToGroups() in your process, just play around a tinker for a bit ;)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, looking at your answer it gave me the some of the hints to make it work, I was able to create the groups by geography and was able to nest the country
ClientsController
$table_companies = Clients::selectRaw('geography geography, country country')->groupBy('geography', 'country')->get()->toArray();
return view('about.our-clients', compact('our-clients', 'table_companies'));

Comment: I actually need 3 @foreach, geography(region), country & company names

Answer (score 1):

You would change your `groupBy` clause to use request parameters:

```
...
->groupBy('company', request()->get('geography'), 'country', 'industry', 'bold')
->get()
->toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupBy()` after getting all records to get it as a `group of records` associate with `geography`.

```
$table_companies = Clients::selectRaw(' name_company company, geography geography, country country, type_industry industry, emphasize bold')   
  ->get()
  ->groupBy('geography')
  ->toArray();
```